# Strange NullPointerException in ternary conditional expression

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, conditional-statements

Can anyone tell me why does Java throw a `NullPointerException` here?

```
Float x = <some condition> ? myObject.getSomeFloat() : 0.0f;
```

- The method `getSomeFloat` returns `Float`.
- Changing `0.0f` to `new Float(0)` works fine.

Comment: myobject is null? Or some object in <some condition> might be null..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The type of this ternary operator is `float`. Therefore, if `myObject.getSomeFloat()` returns null, a `NullPointerException` is thrown when `<some condition>` is true and `myObject.getSomeFloat().floatValue()` is called in order to convert the `Float` to `float`.

[JLS 15.25](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25):

> If one of the second and third operands is of primitive type T, and the type of the other is the result of applying boxing conversion (§5.1.7) to T, then the type of the conditional expression is T.

In your case, you have a primitive type - float - and the Boxed version of that float - Float. Therefore, the type of the conditional expression is the primitive type - float.

Comment: @almasshaikh No, you are wrong. Try `Float x = true ? (Float)null : 0.0f; System.out.println(x);` An arbitrary `null` reference is not the same scenario.

Comment: Wow, that's counterintuitive. (+1)

Comment: This answer is correct - the `getSomeFloat()` method must be returning null, which is auto unboxed... boom. Changing the other value to `Float` prevents the auto unbox - no boom.