# Short form for Java If statement returns NullPointerException when one of the returned objects is null

Tags: java, if-statement, nullpointerexception, null

Why this code returns the error: java.lang.NullPointerException

```
Object obj = null;
Long lNull = null;
Long res = obj == null ? lNull : 10L;
```

But the following way works without any errors:

```
Object obj = null;
Long res = obj == null ? null : 10L;
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25.2 - *"If one of the second and third operands is of primitive type T, and the type of the other is the result of applying boxing conversion (§5.1.7) to T, then the type of the conditional expression is T."*, has been asked before, cannot find the dupe.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17549666/weird-behaviour-when-using-java-ternary-operator

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27730895/strange-nullpointerexception-in-ternary-conditional-expression

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3265948/nullpointerexception-with-autoboxing-in-ternary-expression

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31612888/nullpointerexception-and-unboxing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the second case, the compiler can infer that the `null` must be a `Long` type. In the first case, it doesn't - and assumes that the expression returns a `long`. You can see that this is the case (i.e. fix it) like,

```
Long res = obj == null ? lNull : (Long) 10L;
```

which does not yield a NullPointerException.

Answer (score 4):

The error happens because in your case [the standard requires unboxing the value of a boxed type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25):

> If one of the second and third operands is of primitive type `T`, and the type of the other is the result of applying boxing conversion (§5.1.7) to `T`, then the type of the conditional expression is `T`.

In your case `T` is `long`, because `10L` is `long` and `lNull` is `Long`, i.e. the result of applying boxing conversion to `long`.

The standard further says that

> If necessary, unboxing conversion is performed on the result.

This is what causes the exception. Note that if you invert the condition, the exception would no longer be thrown:

```
Long res = obj != null ? lNull : 10L;
```

You can fix the problem by explicitly asking for `Long` instead of using `long`, i.e.

```
Long res = obj == null ? lNull : Long.valueOf(10L);
```

Answer (score 2):

The [JLS, Section 15.25](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25) talks about the type of the conditional operator expression for various combinations of the types of the second and third operands.  There are lots of tables mapping the two types in all relevant combinations to the result type.

> ```
> 3rd → long
> 2nd ↓  
> ...
> Long  long
> ...
> null  lub(null,Long)
> ```

Your first example has a `Long` and a `long`, which yields `long`.  This requires `lNull` to be unboxed, which explains the `NullPointerException`.

Your second example has a `null` *literal* (not a `null` variable) and a `long`.  This results in "lub(null,Long)" or `Long`, and no unboxing is performed, so no NPE is observed.

You can avoid the NPE by using your first example or by casting `10L` as a `Long`, because a `null` and a `Long` yield a `Long`.

> ```
> 3rd → Long
> 2nd ↓  
> ...
> Long  Long
> ```